# How necessary it is to have PhD students?

Tags: mathematics, career-path, supervision

If a person has a tenure/ tenure track position on a math department, how obligatory it is to have PhD students? While some people like to have students, there are people who do not like that.

I am particularly interested about the situation in American universities.

Comment: In short, it depends on university and field. Of course, in experimental science with labs it is impossible to do without grad students. In math, it also depends on the size of the program: in my view, if there are X professors and about 1.5X or less grad students, then not everyone should be expected to have one

Comment: Cynicism Alert: You need people to all the research tasks (your ideas, right?). PhD students have the best (lowest) wage:skill ratio.

Comment: @Crowley In many places, the cost of Ph.D. students is not just wages but also tuition waivers. As a result postdocs and Ph.D. students may have surprisingly similar costs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It certainly depends on the department you're in. Some departments have small PhD programs and largely focused on undergraduate and master's programs. In that case, you may get away with just not having PhD students. On the other hand, at most Research-1 universities, math departments have 1.5-2 PhD students per tenure-track faculty. Of course, faculty do not evenly assume mentorship roles for them, but there is an expectation that one does, in fact, supervise some. It is not uncommon to have an expectation that, for example, one has to have graduated one PhD student before promotion to full professor.

In general, the way to see this most productively is probably to remember that a university is an institution of higher education. If a department has a PhD program as an important component, then it is a reasonably expectation that every tenure-track faculty participates in it by (i) teaching graduate courses, and (ii) advising PhD students. If you actively try to get out of one or both of these parts of your job, you're not doing your job. The situation is no different than teaching and service: it's part of your job, and whether you do or do not like this part makes no difference in the expectations that are put on you.

Comment: "If you actively try to get out of one or both of these parts of your job, you're not doing your job" I would strongly disagree with that. Everyone has his/her strengths and weaknesses and, if the department is reasonably balanced as a whole, I see no reason to demand that *everyone* participate in *everything*. You cannot get away with doing *nothing*, but if you do your fair share time and effort-wise, there is nothing shameful or immoral about opting out of some activities that others can do better than you or that you just dislike as long as there is no shortage of hands for them.

Comment: @fedja No one expects people to do everything.  But teaching plus research plus service is not everything.  Every department I know of requires teaching plus research for promotions--and says so when they solicit evaluations for promotion cases.  And they want candidates to do *well* at each.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty "Teaching" doesn't even necessarily mean "graduate teaching", much less "supervising a PhD student", right? Also, one of the most common schemes is 2-2-1 weighted average and having 10-10-0 score is often not any worse than 8-8-8, say. What is true is that the promotion rules vary a lot with the department, so you, indeed, should consult the faculty handbooks for the minima. However, even those are not a dogma and exceptions can be made.

Comment: For instance, one of our faculty members spent several years on setting and running a teacher education program (and brought a few millions in grants in the process) *but* that came at a cost of her research. Should she be promoted to the full professor rank? The handbook says "No, the number of publications for the last 5 years is short of the required minimum" while the common sense says "Yes, she has made way more useful work for the department than an average guy who gets a promotion and she couldn't possibly do it without sacrificing some other stuff". What to do?

Comment: @fedja, the point I'm making is that you can't just "opt out". A tenure-track faculty's job is understood to include PhD student supervision if your department has a significant PhD program. You can't unilaterally decide that you're not interested in this, and at a later point expect that your colleagues will simply "understand". If you don't want to supervise graduate students in general, you need to talk to your head of department and have your job description changed. That may include getting other duties. This reassignment is recorded, and will be part of promotion proceedings.